# Transporting chicken between refrigerators - how long is too long?

Tags: chicken, refrigerator, spoilage, food-safety, food-transport

My work lunch routine currently consists of cooking chicken over the weekend and refrigerating it, then cutting up a piece and adding it with rice and vegetables in a refrigerated, sealed tupperware container the night before work. In the morning I take the container out of the fridge and put it in my backpack, where it stays for about 2 and 1/2 hours (or a little more) through my morning commute. As soon as I get to work I put it back in a refrigerator, microwave it and eat it about 4 hours later. Is this too long out of the refrigerator to safely eat?

Comment: As you can see from the generalized version of your question, it is unsafe to leave food out in the danger zone for 2+ hours. However there are insulated lunch bags with ice packs that you can use to prevent your food from being in the danger zone for so long. Also I just want to say how sorry I am that you have to deal with a 2.5 hr commute.

Comment: @Jay that sounds like an answer to me.  Perhaps you could post one?

Comment: @JTL generally questions like these will be closed due to fact that seasoned advice gets questions very similar to these asked every couple of days. The normal procedure is to close the question as a duplicate of the question cindy posted above. I just wanted to comment so the OP would have some additional information.